# My TV keeps spamming Windows Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, device-manager, dlna

[image: Devices]

Anything I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but I blocked my TV's IP via Windows Firewall, so it cannot connect to my PC anymore.

Since DLNA is also broken on this TV, I won't miss anything.